# Meteor - alternative layout template

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

I have a layout template but want to apply an alternative layout template. I have created altLayout.html but how do I apply it to my route?

```
Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'layout',
        notFoundTemplate: 'pageNotFound',
      //waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('items'); }

    });

    Router.map(function() {
      this.route('main', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'main',
         notFoundtemplate: "pageNotFound",
         oldBrowserTemplate: "oldBrowser",
          onBeforeAction: function () {
                // render the unsupported browser page if user isn't using Chrome
                if(BrowserDetect.browser == "Chrome"){
                    layoutTemplate: 'altLayout',
                    this.render('oldBrowser');
                    this.stop();
                }
          },
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
Router.route("/product/:id",
{
  name: "product_page",
  template: "product_page",
  layoutTemplate: "product_page_layout",
  data: function()
  {
    return {id: this.params.id}
  }
});
```

The "product_page_layout" is where your altLayout.html template goes. Basically:

```
Router.map(function() {
      this.route('main', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'main',
        layoutTemplate: "altLayout",
         notFoundtemplate: "pageNotFound",
         oldBrowserTemplate: "oldBrowser",
          onBeforeAction: function () {
                // render the unsupported browser page if user isn't using Chrome
                if(BrowserDetect.browser == "Chrome"){
                    layoutTemplate: 'altLayout',
                    this.render('oldBrowser');
                    this.stop();
                }
          },
      });

    });
```